# Insert Data using Json in C#

Tags: c#, php, json

I have some problem in inserting data to my free webhost mysql using JSON in C#. This is what I have done :

> Php

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP REQUEST Request
 */
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
    //require_once __DIR__ . '/generateIDrandom.php';
    require_once __DIR__ . '/Configuration.php';
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();
    $connstring = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_REQUEST['WSID'])) {
    $wsid = $_REQUEST['WSID'];
    $jenismesin = $_REQUEST['JenisMesin'];
    $merk = $_REQUEST['MerkMesin'];
        $lokasi = $_REQUEST['Lokasi'];
    $inlok = $_REQUEST['InisialLokasi'];
    $limit = $_REQUEST['LimitMesin'];
        $denom = $_REQUEST['Denom'];
    $tim4 = $_REQUEST['Tim4'];
    $tim5 = $_REQUEST['Tim5'];
    $status = "1";

    // connecting to db
    $result = mysqli_query($connstring, "insert into MasterATM (WSID, JenisMesin, MerkMesin, Lokasi, InisialLokasi, LimitMesin, Denom, Tim4, Tim5, Status) values ('$wsid','$jenismesin','$merk','$lokasi', '$inlok', '$limit', '$denom','$tim4','$tim5','$status')");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Upload Successfully";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

> C#

```
private void InputBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://xxx.000webhostapp.com/php/InsertDataMesin.php?WSID =" + WSIDBox.Text + "& JenisMesin = " + TipeMesinBox.SelectedItem + "& MerkMesin = " + MerkMesinCB.SelectedItem + "& Lokasi= " + LokasiBox.Text + "& InisialLokasi = " + InisialLokasiBox.Text + "& LimitMesin= " + LimitBox.Text + "& Denom= " + DenomBox.Text + "& Tim4= '" + Tim4CB.SelectedItem + "& Tim5= '" + Tim5CB.SelectedItem + "& Status = 1");
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string json = stream.ReadToEnd();

            stream.Close();
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

            MessageBox.Show("Data berhasil ditambahkan !");

            TampilDataEdit();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Data gagal ditambahkan. Silakan coba lagi");
        }
}
```

When I run my program, there is no some error. But when I see to my database, there is no data inserted. So, How can I insert data using json c# ?

Comment: "inserting data to my free webhost phpmyadmin ". Just to clarify some terminology, you don't insert data to phpMyAdmin. You insert data to MySQL - when you do this through your code, phpMyAdmin doesn't come into it. phpMyAdmin is just a GUI (one of many) by which you can interact with your MySQL database. Underneath it uses code just like yours to do that job. I'm splitting hairs but I find it helps to be clear about the tools you're using and what they actually do.

Comment: Ahh thanks for your clarification. I mean, I want to insert data to mysql not phpmyadmin. Can you help me ?

Comment: P.S. Your page is horribly vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You aren't validating or escaping the data, or using parameters in the query. A malicious user could call your endpoint with certain values and use it to steal, corrupt or destroy your data easily. Also there's a chance that data you submit in the query parameters could cause a syntax error in the query. Research how to use parameterised queries. Also, in the C#, if there _is_ any error, you're ignoring it - you should at least log it before you show the message box. And you might need to URLEncode what you send from C#

Comment: A good way to narrow down your problem here though would be to call your endpoint using another tool such as PostMan or SOAPUI, then we can rule in/out the C# part as the cause of the issue. Also get mysqli to report the last error, if any. And get it to dump out what the final SQL string looks like before you run it, and try running that directly in phpMyAdmin to see if it works. Those are some basic debugging steps you can take.

Comment: @Obaja: The result that you get from deserializing the json variable, should tell you if something went wrong. If no excpetion is thrown the webrequest itself should be good, but something is wrong with the content. Look into result.